# On the common compact support for a convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in L^1$. I guess it is true that there are $f_n$ s.t. $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^1$ and $\mathcal{F}(f_n)$ has compact support for each $n$.   Can I conclude somehow that there is a compact set $K$ s.t. $supp {\mathcal{F}(f_n)}\subset K$ for all $n>N$ for some N? Here $\mathcal{F}$ denotes Fourier Transform.

Comment: Carl,  I deleted my answer since I did not understand that your question involves the Fourier transform.  Perhaps you should write the word "Fourier"  somewhere in the question since a single $\mathcal F$ might not be enoughtto let people know that the Fourier transform is involved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g$ be defined on $\mathbb R$ by
$$
  g(x) = e^{-x^2}, \quad \forall x\in  \mathbb R,
  $$
and let $f$ be the inverse Fourier transform of $g$.  Since $g$ is in the
Schwartz space $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$, we have that $f$ is also in $\mathscr S(\mathbb R)$ and, in particular $f$ lies
in $L^1(\mathbb R)$.

We will show that there is no sequence $\{f_n\}_n$ converging to $f$ in $L^1(\mathbb R)$, and such that the support of all
the Fourier transforms
$\hat f_n$ lie in a single compact set $K$.

Assuming otherwise, we have that $\hat f_n\to \hat f$, at least pointwise,  so one concludes that $\hat f$
vanishes off $K$. However $\hat f=g$, which vanishes nowhere, giving a contradiction.